# Jquery mobile form wont submit nor post input to php script

Tags: php, android, jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi i almost got everything ,but i dont know whats wrong. i have two pages . search.php :with jquery allow choosing a type of a product and submit the input to the index.php : (no jquery just simple html/php page) that show the results from my database
when i click submit button , a loading window popup , and nothing happens ! i already got this to work when i code the search.php without jquery but it looks ugly in android browser :/

here is my codes :

http://textuploader.com/?p=6&id=dmLX

and please help me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your page "index.php", you forgot the open body tag. Moreover, your index.php must be "compatible" with jquerymobile structure : add an attribute data-role=page" on your first div. Like this :

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" class="type-interior">
<?php while($myproducts = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?> 
<table width="800" height ="479" border="0" background="includes/images/result_box.png">
  <tr>
    <td id="Prix"><?php echo $myproducts['Product_Price']." Dollars" ;?> <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<?php }  ?>
</body>
```

Comment: in my code i have the body tag , just didnt see that while copying .. . and thanks the data-role kinda solved the problem , but it only display the first result , any idea?